# Is it possible to export shape keys to c4d pose morph?

Tags: export, shape-keys

I try to export a model with shapekeys (a ManuelBastioni character), in order to import it in c4d. Is there a way to transfer these data to the equivalent in c4d (posemorph tag) ?
I'm almost sure I've already done that, but I can't remember anymore how...

Thx,

J

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed how to do it :
In the blender fbx export options, "apply modifiers" must **be unchecked** :

[image]

Import fbxinto c4d, and so are the blender's shape keys converted to c4d's pose morph :

[image]